# I am trying to access external storage directory, to get songs list and display they in RecyclerView

Tags: android

It's different from just null pointer exception because it runs fine on android version less then or equal to 6

Previously I was getting error that the thread is doing to much of work and thus it skipped many frames so i tried to run it on different thread But I am getting this error. Any suggestion is highly appreciated. As I am a beginner and also it runs fine on my device Android version 6.0 But not on device of higher version. Can anyone answer why?

```
enter code here
```

public class Musiclist extends AppCompatActivity {

```
public static ArrayList<File> mymusics;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
Adpterformymusic adpterformymusic;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.musiclistd);

    mymusics=new ArrayList<>();
    recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recycleview);

    peeMission();


    Runnable runnable=new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

         mymusics=findsongs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
        adpterformymusic=new Adpterformymusic(Musiclist.this,mymusics);

         recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Musiclist.this));
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adpterformymusic);
        }


        public ArrayList<File> findsongs(File file)
        {
            ArrayList<File> mosiac=new ArrayList<>();
            File [] files=file.listFiles();
            assert files != null;
            Log.d("checking length of file",String.valueOf(files.length));
            for(File single:files)
            {
                if(single.isDirectory() && !single.isHidden())
                {
                    mosiac.addAll(findsongs(single));
                }
                else
                {
                    if(single.getName().endsWith(".mp3"))
                    {

                        mosiac.add(single);
                    }
                }

            }


            return mosiac;
        }

    };
    Thread thread=new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();


}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
public void peeMission()
{
    if(checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {


    }
    else
    {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(Musiclist.this
                ,new String[] {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},2);
    }


}
```

}

this is java code to get songs list, In my logcat it show's

> Logcat

```
Logcat 2020-12-13 22:47:33.094 12296-12377/com.example.read_it1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-2
Process: com.example.read_it1, PID: 12296
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
    at com.example.read_it1.Musiclist$1.findsongs(Musiclist.java:60)
    at com.example.read_it1.Musiclist$1.run(Musiclist.java:47)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: android studio is just an IDE, meaning that it helps you to code. please use the `android` tag and not `android-studio`, unless your question actually is regarding the IDE itself

Comment: Your arrayList which holds the file is null please check the list it should not be null

Comment: Also put your problem in the post itself. Not only in the subject. Never refer to the subject.